# Activating virtualenv from inside a running Python3 session

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

The documentation for `virtualenv` says that to activate an environment from inside python, use

```
activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

But `execfile` does not exist in Python 3. If I try to use `exec(open("venv/bin/activate_this.py").read())`, it complains

```
AssertionError: You must run this like execfile('path/to/activate_this.py', dict(__file__='path/to/activate_this.py'))
```

And that makes sense, because `activate_this.py` makes reference to `__file__`.

How do I activate virtualenv from inside python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `__file__` in globals:

```
exec(open("venv/bin/activate_this.py").read(), {'__file__': "venv/bin/activate_this.py"})
```